# Move PostgreSQL temporary file location

Tags: postgresql

How do I move the PostgreSQL temporary file / cache location? I have limited space on my system partition so it keeps throwing me errors like this one:

```
ERROR: could not extend file "base/16384/16563.1": wrote only 4096 of 8192 bytes at block 207279
SQL state: 53100
Hint: Check free disk space.
```

Answer (score 2):

To control where PostgreSQL puts temporary files, you first create one or more [tablespaces](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtablespace.html) to hold the temp files, then you set the [temp_tablespaces](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TEMP-TABLESPACES) configuration variable to specify those tablespaces.

It is important the tablespace directory continue to exist after a restart. It's OK for tempfiles to vanish from within it, but the target directory *must* exist or PostgreSQL will fail to start.

You can even give an explicit `tablespace` parameter to a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...` etc, allowing you to control where things go to distribute I/O around if you know more about the workload than the database server does.